# How to change sorting order when sorting mixed items with String.localeCompare?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Let's say we have an array of objects with mixed `name` values (nums, cyrillic, english):

(If the code doesn't work for you, change `undefined` to `'ru'`, it will also change the sorting structure)

```js
let ascending = true

var items = [
  {name: 'c', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'b', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'a', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'д', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'в', value: ''}, 
  {name: '41', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'а', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'б', value: ''}, 
  {name: '0', value: ''}, 
  {name: '31', value: ''}, 
  {name: '4', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'г', value: ''}
]

items.sort(function (a, b) {
  // ascending order
  if (ascending) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, { numeric: true });
  }
  // descending order
  else {
    return b.name.localeCompare(a.name, undefined, { numeric: true });
  }
})

console.log(items);
```

### Current result

I get the sorted array in **ascending** order with the following structure:

- Nums (ascending)
- English (ascending)
- Non-english (ascending)

Result when `ascending = true`:

```
{name: "0", value: ""}
{name: "31", value: ""}
{name: "4", value: ""}
{name: "41", value: ""}
{name: "a", value: ""}
{name: "b", value: ""}
{name: "c", value: ""}
{name: "а", value: ""}
{name: "б", value: ""}
{name: "в", value: ""}
{name: "г", value: ""}
{name: "д", value: ""}
```

### Desired result

I need it to be able to sort the array in **descending** order when `ascending = false` and **retain the structure**:

- Nums (descending)
- English (descending)
- Non-english (descending)

Needed result when `ascending = false`:

```
{name: "41", value: ""}
{name: "31", value: ""}
{name: "4", value: ""}
{name: "0", value: ""}    
{name: "c", value: ""}
{name: "b", value: ""}
{name: "a", value: ""}
{name: "д", value: ""}
{name: "г", value: ""}
{name: "в", value: ""}
{name: "б", value: ""}
{name: "а", value: ""}
```

### Problem

When I change `ascending = false` and change positions of `b.name` with `a.name` it just flips the whole array upside down instead of flipping the values in their "category" (nums, english, cyrillic).

I'm not sure how to do it properly. I mean, reversing the array reverses the values, so should I just restructure the array "categories" after it flipped the array? Something like this maybe:

- get all the objects with numbers with `isNaN()` and move them on top
- then get items containing only `a-z` at `[0]` and move them below the numbers "category"
- everything else just stays on the bottom

Comment: append `.reverse()` at the end of the `.sort()`

Comment: It means you simply can't use `localeCompare` if you want to split the items into individual categories

Comment: @Adelin calling `reverse` on the array doesn't do anything different than inverting the sort (like toggling `ascending` already does)

Comment: @Bergi hmm, do you know of any other way to sort such a mixed array that would also retain the needed structure?

Comment: @Un1 Get the "category" of each item, then first compare the categories.

Answer (score 2):

If you are have a mechanism to identify numbers, english and non-english strings you can use the following idea:

```js
var items = [
  { name: "c", value: "" },
  { name: "b", value: "" },
  { name: "a", value: "" },
  { name: "д", value: "" },
  { name: "в", value: "" },
  { name: "41", value: "" },
  { name: "а", value: "" },
  { name: "б", value: "" },
  { name: "0", value: "" },
  { name: "31", value: "" },
  { name: "4", value: "" },
  { name: "г", value: "" }
];

function sortFunctionMaker(ascending) {
  function isNumber(str) {
    return Number.isNaN(Number(str)) === false;
  }

  function isEnglish(str) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str);
  }

  return function(a, b) {
    var aw, bw;

    if (isNumber(a.name)) {
      aw = 1;
    } else if (isEnglish(a.name)) {
      aw = 2;
    } else {
      aw = 3;
    }
    if (isNumber(b.name)) {
      bw = 1;
    } else if (isEnglish(b.name)) {
      bw = 2;
    } else {
      bw = 3;
    }

    if (aw !== bw) {
      // a and b belong to different categories
      // no further comparison is needed
      return aw - bw;
    } else if (aw === 1) {
      // both are numbers
      // sort mathematically
      return (ascending ? 1 : -1) * (a.name - b.name);
    } else {
      // both are english or otherwise
      // sort using localeCompare
      return (ascending ? 1 : -1) * a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    }
  }
}

items.sort(sortFunctionMaker(true));
console.log("Ascending");
items.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.name);
});

items.sort(sortFunctionMaker(false));
console.log("Descending");
items.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.name);
});
console.groupEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my solution I:

1. first group the data into 3 categories (arrays):
   `"nums"`, `"en"`, `"nonen"`;
2. sort each of them;
3. place them in a single array, in the proper order

   ```js
   var ascending = true;
   var english = /^[A-Za-z]/;
   var items = [
     {name: 'c', value: ''}, 
     {name: 'b', value: ''}, 
     {name: 'a', value: ''}, 
     {name: 'д', value: ''}, 
     {name: 'в', value: ''}, 
     {name: '41', value: ''}, 
     {name: 'а', value: ''}, 
     {name: 'б', value: ''}, 
     {name: '0', value: ''}, 
     {name: '31', value: ''}, 
     {name: '4', value: ''}, 
     {name: 'г', value: ''}
   ];

   var groups = items.reduce((acc,currentVal)=>{
     if(!isNaN(parseInt(currentVal.name))) {
       acc[0].push(currentVal); // first array will contain nums
     } else if(english.test(currentVal.name)){
       acc[1].push(currentVal); //second will contain english chars
     } else {
       acc[2].push(currentVal) // last will contain rest chars
     }
     return acc;
     
   },[[],[],[]]);

   var sortFunc = function(a,b){
       return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, { numeric: true });
   }
   var groupSorted = [];
   groups.forEach(group => groupSorted.push(...ascending?group.sort(sortFunc):group.sort(sortFunc).reverse()));
   console.log(groupSorted);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to restructure the flipped array afterwards just by moving sorted "categories" into needed positions:

- Nums (descending)
- English (descending)
- Non-english (descending)

```js
let ascending = false

var items = [
  {name: 'c', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'b', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'a', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'д', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'в', value: ''}, 
  {name: '41', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'а', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'б', value: ''}, 
  {name: '0', value: ''}, 
  {name: '31', value: ''}, 
  {name: '4', value: ''}, 
  {name: 'г', value: ''}
]

items.sort(function (a, b) {
  // ascending order
  if (ascending) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, { numeric: true });
  }
  // descending order
  else {
    return b.name.localeCompare(a.name, undefined, { numeric: true });
  }
})


if (ascending == false) {
  var englishAlphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  let nums = []
  let english = []
  let other = []

  items.forEach(element => {
    if (isNaN(element.name[0]) == false) {
      nums.push(element)
    }
    else if (englishAlphabet.includes(element.name[0].toLowerCase())) {
      english.push(element)
    }
    else {
      other.push(element)
    }
  });

  let restructuredItems = nums.concat(english).concat(other)

  console.log('BEFORE RESTRUCTURING', items);
  console.log('AFTER RESTRUCTURING: ', restructuredItems);
}
```